# Does anyone have experience on running MapReduce on LXC containers?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, containers, lxc

I just have some questions about the performance of Hadoop based on LXC.

So I am wondering if anyone have such kind of experince before? Is there any impressive improvements of performance like mem or disk usage?

It will be nice if you have any test data to share with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good news is that lxc is almost the same as native considering performance tests!

Comparing with the VM (kvm), we have some basic results here:

```
CPU：native（lxc）and vm are almost the same

MEM：VM performance is about 1/2 of native (lxc)

DISK：VM write performance is 2/3 of native, read performance 1/2

NETWORK：VM has twice network latency than native
```